# URL encoding for document.location.href

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

I am building an iFrame and am using document.location.href -> my exact code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=" + document.location.href + "&layout=standard&show_faces=false&action=like&font=verdana&colorscheme=light' frameborder=0></iframe>");
</script>
```

This is working great for all of my pages except one. I believe the issue with the one page is caused by a dash "-" being in the page name. My questions is - is there a way to encode my src differently so that the link works? The CORRECT URL I want it to pull is:

[]/products/Product%252dExample.html

But what it IS pulling in is:

[]/products/Product-Example.html

And this is causing the page to not work correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) function will do what you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=" + encodeURIComponent( document.location.href ) + "&layout=standard&show_faces=false&action=like&font=verdana&colorscheme=light' frameborder=0></iframe>");
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, `encodeURIComponent('Product-Example')` yields `Product-Example`, which is what normally should be in an URI. `%252d` is a strange invalid double-percent-encoding for the hyphen. Tyler, are you sure that is what you need?

Comment: Thanks Jacob - I thought that would work, but it didn't.. It looks as though the URL is already encoded correctly on my side, but its on the facebook side that it is interpreting it incorrectly.. Are you familiar with the new facebook functionality at all? Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Facebook like buttons double encode the page uri of the target page
so the way to get what you're looking for is...

encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent( document.location.href ))

Oh those wacky FB guys.

Comment: this solved a different problem for me: dynamically generating links on the client side with url-encoded names. When I only encoded once, the browser sent a request to the decoded URL, which was undesirable for me. Thank you!